# implementing template page in cakephp2.2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am new to cakephp and gone through the documentation of cakephp. I felt its a useful framework for the developers. And I started implementing into my project. I want to use a web template page and want to incorporate cakephp in that template. I tried doing that, I am getting errors. Can you guys please assist me the process of including template , like where to keep the files and folders. where to keep my index/home page  file of a template?
how to include this file in controllers & views,routes?

Comment: should post your code in which you are getting errors..

Comment: `I am new to cakephp and gone through the documentation of cakephp` In that case you have to go through it once again http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html

Answer (score 1):

you need to make

> layout

for that I guess.
Which will contain the header footer section and the

> view

will be called into it
according to the section which is getting displayed.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html

Comment: I created path cake/app/View/themed/mbsample/
copied folders from app/view/ to cake/app/View/themed/mbsample/Elements,Errors,Emails,Helper,Layouts,Scaffolds,webroot
in mbsample/webroot  I created css,img,js folders to keep template related files.
and in /view/themed/mbsample/Layouts/ i copied template index file and renamed as mbsample.ctp

And in AppController.php, In AppController class, I added these variables:
    public $view   = 'Theme';  
    public $theme = 'mbsample';  
 trying to run the file from localhost but its giving errros.
Please advice me, based on the above details

Comment: Thanks for everybody for taking time and reply me.finally I could able to run the template page. I have to name the layout/mbsample.ctp as layout/default.ctp.

Comment: Are you aware of the functioning of Cake?